# ERROR: npm ERR! code EOVERRIDE npm ERR! Override for axios@^1.2.0 conflicts with direct dependency

Tags: azure, axios, dependencies, chatbot

I have built an Azure chatbot that works fine in Bot Emulator locally but fails when I upload it to Azure. I get the following error:

npm ERR! code EOVERRIDE
npm ERR! Override for axios@^1.2.0 conflicts with direct dependency

I'm not entirely sure what this means. Does anyone know how to get around this?

I have tried to update the Axios package in both package-lock and package json files and nothing has worked

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Override for react-error-overlay@^6.0.9 conflicts with direct dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74734456/override-for-react-error-overlay6-0-9-conflicts-with-direct-dependency)

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to the impact of packages in npm library related to axios package. We need to override the package manually using the below code block.

```
npm install axios-method-override

import axiosMethodOverride from 'axios-method-override';
 
axiosMethodOverride(axios);
 
const instance = axios.create();
axiosMethodOverride(instance);
```

we need to use override patch of HTTP, PUT, DELETE in this implementation.