# Override for react-error-overlay@^6.0.9 conflicts with direct dependency

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, dependencies, package.json

I have changed my node version and keep getting this error if I try to install another package or just try to run `npm install`. Here is the error message:

> npm ERR! code EOVERRIDE
>
> npm ERR! Override for react-error-overlay@^6.0.9 conflicts with direct dependency
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-12-08T16_39_09_063Z-debug-0.log`

My **package.json** file is below:

```
{
  "name": "kamamini",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "author": "Moctar Yonli",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^28.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-decoupled-document": "^28.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react": "^3.0.2",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.5.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
    "@firebase/auth-interop-types": "^0.1.5",
    "@glidejs/glide": "^3.5.2",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@metismenu/react": "0.0.2",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.0.5",
    "@mui/material": "^5.0.6",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.0.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.7.1",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "firebase": "^8.4.1",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "framer-motion": "^4.1.17",
    "gh-pages": "^3.2.3",
    "history": "^5.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "^1.5.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-confetti": "^6.1.0",
    "react-currency-format": "^1.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dropzone": "^11.3.2",
    "react-helmet-async": "^1.3.0",
    "react-html-parser": "^2.0.2",
    "react-image-gallery": "^1.0.9",
    "react-material-ui-carousel": "^2.2.6",
    "react-payment-inputs": "^1.1.9",
    "react-player": "^2.9.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "react-share": "^4.4.0",
    "react-slick": "^0.28.1",
    "react-swipeable-views": "^0.14.0",
    "react-toastify": "^7.0.3",
    "react-use": "^17.4.0",
    "reactstrap": "^8.9.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.0",
    "yup": "^0.32.9"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "``eslintConfig``": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "`browserslist`": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "overrides": {
    "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-error-overlay": "^6.0.9"
  }
}
```

Why do I get this error when trying to install a package?
[image: Screen with error message]

Answer (score 14):

As per the [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json?v=true#overrides)

> You may not set an override for a package that you directly depend on unless both the dependency and the override itself share the exact same spec.

Your override for `react-error-overlay` specifies `6.0.9` (i.e. the exact version), while your `devDependencies` specifies `^6.0.9` (i.e. match 6.0.9 or any patch release above). These specs are not exactly the same, so you get the error.

You can fix it by:

- updating your `overrides` to use `^6.0.9`
- updating your `devDependencies` to use `6.0.9`
- updating your `overrides` to use `"react-error-overlay": "$react-error-overlay"` which tells it to use the version referenced in the dependencies directly

> To make this limitation easier to deal with, overrides may also be defined as a reference to a spec for a direct dependency by prefixing the name of the package you wish the version to match with a `$`.

Comment: Confirmed.
The version specification in an "overrides" clause must *either*
be "$‹the-package-name›" – *or* –  it must be *literally* the same
as the version of the package that package.json *directly* depends on.
Thus, if it's not "$react-error-overlay", then ***both***
versions must be `~6.0.9` *or* `^6.0.9` *or* `6.0.9`.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75253708) is correct.

#### Reproducing your findings

Thanks for including the `package.json` in your question! 
As a result, anyone can [reproduce your findings](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

In a completely empty directory, I added your `package.json`, and then
ran `npm install`.

The response is in the following screenshot.

[image: 'npm ERR! code EOVERRIDE']

The *recommended* action is to define the version as a *reference* to
the package used as a direct dependency.
Replace `6.0.9` with `$react-error-overlay` in the `overrides` clause.

```
  "overrides": {
    "react-error-overlay": "$react-error-overlay"
  },
```

This has the advantage of automatically adjusting the version in
`overrides`, if the version in `devDependencies` ever changes in
the future.

#### You have more work to do

Fixing the `EOVERRIDE` error *doesn't* mean you're all set to start
working on your project. 
Running `npm install` now results in an `ERESOLVE` error. 
You've solved the `EOVERRIDE` error.
Now you need to solve the `ERESOLVE` error …

[image: 'npm ERR! code ERESOLVE']

Answer (score -4):

You just have to remove the overrides section of your package.json file.